# [mysql]SQL to retrieve tree data but some different order

Tags: mysql, tree

Here's a IA I need to express.(tree model)

```
about us
    company
        history
        location
    ceo
product
    mobile
        iphone
        galaxy 3
```

And this is HTML DOM I need to make. As you see, `depth2` and `depth3`(up to 5 or 6) are in the same level of DOM and depth1 has them as children.(I have to make this way because of CSS)

```
<div class="depth1"><span>about us</span>

    <div class="depth2">company</div>   
    <div class="depth2">ceo</div><!--CEO is here! not below "location" -->

    <div class="depth3">history</div>   
    <div class="depth3">location</div>

</div>


<div class="depth1"><span>product</span>

    <div class="depth2">mobile</div>

    <div class="depth3">iphone</div>    
    <div class="depth3">galaxy 3</div>

</div>
```

And data is inserted in `mysql` like this. (`p_id` means parent's id)

```
id(pk)  p_id    level   order   name
------------------------------------------
1       root        0       0       -
2       1       1       100     about us
3       7       2       100     mobile
4       5       3       200     location
5       2       2       100     company
6       5       3       100     history
7       1       1       200     product
8       3       3       100     iphone
9       3       3       200     galaxy
10      2       2       200     ceo
```

I tried to `order by level, order` but the result is not proper.(The order should be same as HTML DOM order)

```
id(pk)  p_id    level   order   name
------------------------------------------
1       root        0       0       -
2       1       1       100     about us
7       1       1       200     product
3       7       2       100     mobile
5       2       2       100     company
10      2       2       200     ceo
8       3       3       100     iphone
6       5       3       100     history
4       5       3       200     location
9       3       3       200     galaxy
```

How could I order same as HTML order?

The hardest part is `depth2` or `depth3` is in line(as a group) below their parent(depth1).

```
id(pk)  p_id    level   order   name
------------------------------------------
1       root        0       0       -
2       1       1       100     about us
5       2       2       100     company
10      2       2       200     ceo
6       5       3       100     history
4       5       3       200     location
7       1       1       200     product
3       7       2       100     mobile
8       3       3       100     iphone
9       3       3       200     galaxy 3
```

I made a `jQuery` code that solves my problem. But I can't apply `jQuery` because actual data is so large(several hundreds) that it takes some annoying time to rearrange HTML elements. I can't burden client-side.

I searched how to [improve jQuery performance](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/). But I have to consider the users javascript disabled.

Please share your different point of view or fresh idea even tricks.(express language is JSP) Thanks.

Comment: if you have to use MySQL and not able to change the table structure you can use a stored procedure to build your result. MySQL is not able to run recursive queries as some other RDBMS can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen, it's possible to pull the data from the database with a simple query, and then write code that populates a tree structure with that data.

I'm not sure why you think that the only options are at the extreme ends of the process - the database and the presentation layer.

You don't say what programming language you are using in the middle tier - I'm guessing it's not JavaScript with jQuery. Whatever it is, your middle tier, server-side language that's executing the database query is surely better suited to creating the tree structure than client-side javascript.

If you really must do this in the database for some reason, I'd suggest a stored procedure.

Also note that some other databases have hierarchical query syntax (like Oracle's 'CONNECT BY') for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah actually I got a stored procedure from somewhere. But I couldn't modify it. I solve the problem in programming language as you suggested. Thank you.