# Conditional order by in MYSQL. Should affect part of row

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

[image]

The left table is a result of my query. And I need to sort it as the right table.

I need to `order by p_id`, if `level >= 2`. The blue box of right table is a target of `order by`.

Is it possible? Of course it is an example. Actual data is hundreds and really need to be sorted.

I searched a lot, but coudln't find the same case.

edit : this table will be returned as `java.util.ArrayList`. If this kind of 'order by' is not possilbe, is it possible in `java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: So it's sorted by id if level < 2 ? Ah, no - you want to sort the 'block' that runs from 11-23 in place.

Comment: Ah.. it's not sorted. it comes from a stored procedure obtained somewhere. And I can't totally understand it.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why do you need the data in this order?

Comment: I can't specify target like `11-23`. It should be sorted by `level` value.

Comment: JIM// as you can see in my previous question, the order of query and the order of HTML(that I should express) is different.

Comment: my previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197845/mysqlsql-to-retrieve-tree-data-but-some-different-order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure it's not possible in one query in MySQL.

In your diagram on the right, the ordering has been done in two separate steps:

1. Sort by id
2. Sort each block by p_id if level >= 2

That's quite difficult to do in MySQL as you would need to identify the blocks and then iterate over them, sorting each block separately.

I've done something similar where ordering within blocks was required and then selecting from those ordered blocks. You can view that [here](https://gist.github.com/4498861) but as I said, I think that that SQL code is horribly complicated involving 5 temporary tables. You would probably need fewer temp tables, but it would still be a very complicated procedure, quite slow and hard to maintain.

> "Actual data is hundreds and really need to be sorted."

Is there any reason why you can't just sort it as you want in code?

```
$blockStart = FALSE;
$count = 0;

foreach($dataArray as $data){

   if($blockStart === FALSE){
      $blockStart = $count;
   }

   if($data['level'] < 2){ //Block has finished
       sortBlock($dataArray, $blockStart, $count);
       $blockStart = $count;
   } 

    $count++;
}

sortBlock($dataArray, $blockStart, $count - 1);


function sortBlock($dataArray, $indexStart, $indexEnd){

    //Sort the elements of $dataArray, between $indexStart and $indexEnd inclusive
    //by the value of p_id
}
```

Trying to solve a general programming problem in MySQL when you could solve it in 1/10th of the programmer time (and probably have it perform faster as well) in Java is not a good path to follow.

Comment: As you can see in my previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197845/mysqlsql-to-retrieve-tree-data-but-some-different-order, the order of query and the order of HTML(that I should express) is different.

Comment: Or is it possible in `java` list?

Comment: I don't think it's possible either.  Order by is applied to the entire resultset.  What does bother me about your answer is that you added the "or at least without being horribly complicated", when you have no idea how to do it, even with a "complicated" solution, so I'm not sure why you would suggest that there actually is a way.  It  undercuts the validity of your answer, which is essentially a non-answer.

Comment: @gview I think Danack's answer is entirely reasonable he states it's probably not possible then suggests an alternative.

Comment: @gview I've added a link to some other code that I wrote for similar 'sorting within blocks'. However I think that when an solution to a problem is that painful - particularly when compared to writing 20 lines of code it really becomes a less than worthless solution.

Comment: @Jim, my point was -- there's no reason to undercut it by getting wishy washy about why a procedural approach is probably the only viable solution, given the desired output.  Given the reassertion and the addition of the java code, I'm +1 for the answer.

Comment: I solved the problem with your idea. in `ArrayList`, I separate them into blocks. And I sort each block with my custom `Comparator`. Even though two more `for()` is needed, I made it work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in SQL, but it would be a very, very complicated query in MySQL.  Here is the approach.

(1) Create a subquery that has the original ids and an indicator of whether something is in level 2 or not.  The ids in this table are going to define the final order.

(2) Next, create a separate counter for each group in this above table.  In other databases, you would use `row_number()`.  In my SQL, this requires a correlated subquery.  This provides the mapping from id to the new ordering.

(3) Next, create a counter for each group, but this time with the needed order (by id for the non-level2 group, by your rules for ordering).

(4) Join the tables together to get the matching.

(5) Order by the original id.

Here is an attempt:

```
select altord.*
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id <= t.id and ((t2.level = 2 and t1.level = 2) or (t2.level <> 2 and t1.level <> 2))
             ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) ord join
     (select t.*,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where (t2.id <= t.id and t2.level <> 2 and t.level <> 2) or (t2.level = 2 and t.level = 2 and (t2.pid < t.pid or t2.pid = t.pid and t2.id < t.id)))
             ) as seqnum
    ) altord
    on ord.seqnum = altord.seqnum
order by ord.id
```

I'm not sure if this SQL is correct, but the idea can be implemented in a single query.

Comment: The truth is, the left table is a result of a complated SQL. So it seems very hard to aplly your answer. I couldn't expect the query will be complicated like this. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: @Deckard . . . I was pointing out that it can be done in a single SQL statement.  Your question seemed to ask if that was possible in MySQL, and it is.